# AWS EC2 API CLI tools vs EC2 Command line tool CLI which one is latest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

In my Linux Ubuntu box, I have two variants for tools installed for AWS EC2.

1. AWS CLI v2 installed @ /usr/local/aws-cli/2.4.0
   These provide the unified AWS CLI interface that everyone is used to `aws ec2 <subcmd>`
2. EC2 API command line tools @/usr/bin/ec2-version
   These tools seem to be mer shell scripts wrappers to java invocations of ec2 commands.
   The actual Java files seem to be located in a jar ec2-
   api-tools-1.6.14.1.jar.
   Manage of ec2-version also shows a version of 1.6.14.1 api=2014-05-01

I am trying to write some automation scripts and would like to know which one of these are still supported by AWS. I understand 1st method had two variants AWS CLI v1 and AWS CLI v2, where CLI v1 is deprecated.

Is the 2nd variant EC2-api-tools (Java) also deprecated by Amazon, since the latest version seems to be somewhere in 2014.
Which of these tools versions should I go ahead with my automation?

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is continuously updated. You should use it.

I do not recognise `ec2-api-tools`, so I would recommend that you do not use them.

Comment: One reference doc[1] from amazon I could find, dated 2017, mentions it as deprecated. But I couldn't find the version of the ec2-api-tools that it was referencing.
[1] http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2/ec2-clt.pdf